# Is Amazon EC2 (small/micro instance) a good solution for me given these circumstances?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, tomcat, wordpress

I'm currently running a home Ubuntu server which I use to host a couple personal Wordpress websites, private git repo, and do some other tinkering (deploy some sample web apps, etc). My website gets around 4,000 views a month, so scalability is not a huge concern. Because I don't have a static IP, I'm using Afraid FreeDNS's dynamic DNS services.

I recently moved and forgot how much tinkering had to be done to get my server publicly accessible - port forwarding and other router settings, script set up with new ISP to ensure the updating of my DNS (since I don't have a static ip), changing of server network configurations, etc. It took me awhile to get all these ducks in a row... website was down for a good week. After going through the move and re-thinking things such as electric bills and reliability, I'm wondering if it's time for a change. I've thought about going back to typical webhosting for ~$5-10 a month, but I really enjoy the flexibility and learning I get hosting on my own server.

Would an Amazon small/micro instance be a viable solution given my circumstances (I don't know much about the cloud options out there aside from Amazon)? Can somebody shed light on the hourly pricing? I'm looking for ballpark monthly pricing if I host a couple wordpress websites (~10,000 views a month) and do some small web application hosting (Tomcat). Looking for a less than $20 a month solution.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: look into a VPS, it may suit you better than cloud computing (pay per hours).

Comment: Any suggestions for VPS providers?

Comment: My .0625 bits is this:
Host the sites directly on wordpress.com.  It's easy to set up, constantly and instantly updated, you can personalize your css, and play with your "toy" (experimental) sites for free.  It's cheap, easy, and migrating is a snap...

Comment: @Everett, I appreciate the suggestion. I'd like to have more flexibility than wordpress.com. It's just one piece of the functionality I'd like to have.

Comment: No problem, best of luck.  I look forward to reading the ultimate solution to this though.

Comment: No worries that the topic was closed. Just curious to know where these sort of questions are best directed in the Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a micro Amazon instance is a good starting point and can cover all of your needs.

You could request an Elastic IP (equivalent to static IP) and learn few new tricks on the way.

The good thing as a new user you are entitled to run some of the services for [free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/). Also they support most of the linux distributions so the transition will be non painful. Some concepts are a bit different, though at the start you really don't need to know that.

Have fun ...